# Using NetBeans IDE 7.1 +PHPMD+CodeSniffer

Tags: netbeans-7.1

I am facing some problem while using PHPMD, CodeSniffer tools with NetBeans 7.1.

After configuration when I run these tools on my code base I am getting some errors under "Mess Detector" and "Code Sniffer" that I completely don't understand.

**>>Configuration exception, check settings! See IDE log(org.jmgl.php.codesniffer.BatchInterface) org.xml.sax.SAXParseException**

**>>>>Configuration exception, check settings! See IDE log(org.jmgl.php.messdetecor.BatchInterface) org.xml.sax.SAXParseException**

Are above lines indicating me to correct my IDE configuration?

Please help.

Comment: This just started happening to me as well. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me:

**Tools** --> **Options** --> **PHP** --> **phpCodeSniffer**

At the bottom there is a button **reset cached data**.
Hit the button, change your file, save it, everything should work now!

If it does not work:

Before I did reset the cached data i found this in NetBeans IDE-LOG:

**INFO [org.jmgl.php.SettingsResolver]: No own configuration found under X:/xxx/nbproject/codesniffer.properties** .

Those configuration-files are only loaded when there are some default values missing. So it might help to set some default-values (sniffs, tabsize) in **Tools** --> **Options** --> **PHP** --> **phpCodeSniffer**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Make sure timezone is set correctly in `php.ini`
If not, XML will contain Warning from PHP which makes that XML invalid.